# Playwright - Check if browser has been opened

Tags: typescript, user-interface, testing, automated-tests, playwright

In one of my tests, I click on a link that leads to the browser being opened. I only want to check whether the browser has been opened, as this is enough for me to know that the test was successful.

I know the code if I were to instantiate the browser myself:

```
    (async () => {
    const browser: Browser | null = await chromium.launch();
    
    // Check if the browser was successfully opened
    if (browser) {
    console.log('Browser opened successfully');
    } else {
    console.error('Failed to open the browser');
    }
})();
```

But I can't figure out how to do it if I wasn't the one doing the instantiation.

Comment: Generally, the browser throws when it can't be opened, but the goal here isn't clear. Why would clicking a link cause a browser to be opened in a test? The website shouldn't know about Playwright or Node.

Comment: @ggorlen The test requires me to click on a link to verify that this is possible. As validation, I wanted to check that the browser is opened.

Comment: If you click a link on a website, usually it takes you to another page. Normally, you'd just [assert that the other page was navigated to](https://playwright.dev/docs/writing-tests#assertions) or use [`page.waitForURL`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url).

Comment: @ggorlen The link is not on a website. It is in the plugin that I am testing. Therefore, I do not have an instance of the browser.

Comment: Can you share the plugin?

Comment: @ggorlen unfortunately, i can't.